# JSON Data Formatting

Tags: java, json

I am passing the following JSON object from a .jsp page to a java servlet using JSON.stringify and JQuery.ajax():

```
{"bin":[{"binId":"0","binDetails":[{"productCode":"AU192","qty":"4"},{"productCode":"NE823","qty":"8"}],"comments":"store pickup"},{"binId":"1","binDetails":[{"productCode":"AF634","qty":"2"}],"comments":""},{"binId":"2","binDetails":[{"productCode":"QB187","qty":"3"}],"comments":"international shipping"},{"binId":"3","binDetails":[{"productCode":"AF634","qty":"2"},{"productCode":"QB187","qty":"2"}],"comments":""}]}
```

This is the code in my java servlet:

```
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
String line = null;

try {
   BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
      strBuffer.append(line);
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
}

try {
   JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(strBuffer.toString()));
   // I call a method here and pass jsonObj
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

In the method to which I pass jsonObj I am using jsonObj.length() to find out how many items are in jsonObj and it tells me 1, which in this case I would have expected 3.  I even tried this:

```
JSONObject bins = jsonObj.get("bin");
bins.length();
```

which told me jsonObj.get("bin") was not a JSONObject.  Is my data formatted incorrectly before I pass it from my .jsp or am I using the JSONObject in my java servlet incorrectly?  How do I access the values in the JSONObject?

Comment: It looks like 'bin' is an array, not an object.

Comment: Um. Ok but isn't it an array of objects?

Comment: Yes it is an array of objects.  But, in your second code example, you get the array and then try to store it in an object of type JSONObject.

Comment: You are missing a comma between the product code of the first bin.

Comment: Thanks but that's just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONArray bins = jsonObj.getJSONArray("bin");
bins.length();
```

Comment: This is what worked but I had to convert to JSONArray back to JSONObject back to JSONArray back to JSONObject to read all the data values.  So there must be a better way to format the data so that I didn't have to convert back and forth.